# Can anyone please correct that MySql code,

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In here "FromSt" and "EndSt" are variables.

I wanna run that code in Vb.net.

MySql console command:

select st_distance from addst WHERE st_name IN ("value1","value1");

VB.net code:

```
 Using FindSqlS As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT st_distance FROM addst WHERE st_name = '" & FromSt & "OR" & "'st_name ='" & EndSt & "'", conn)
```

Comment: Please see [6.1.4 Working with Parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) and use parameters instead of concatenating the values in the query string. It will make your programming life much easier.

Comment: I agree with Andrew Morton. Using query parameters makes it easier to write code without making mistakes with imbalanced quotes. It also makes your code safer from SQL injection vulnerabilities. It's win-win!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you left out a quote and added an extra one in another place.  Try this and see if it fixes your issue:

```
Using FindSqlS As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT st_distance FROM addst WHERE st_name = '" & FromSt & "'" & " OR " & "st_name ='" & EndSt & "'", conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Using FindSqlS As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT st_distance FROM addst WHERE st_name = '" & FromSt & "'" & " OR " & "st_name ='" & EndSt & "'", conn)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).